# how to reset after merging a git PR by mistake

Tags: git, github

By mistake I merged a git pull request (someone else has to merge it, not me...) how can I roll back and create the pull request again

this is what I did:

1) created a pull request to merge branchA into branchB (PR #44)

2) (by mistake) merged the pull request #100 (on GitHub site)

3) Clicked the Revert button to "create a new pull request to revert 
these changes" (PR #45)

4) Merged pull request #45

Now I am trying to again create a pull request to merge branchA into branchB but it does not let me because "There aren't any commits to merge" (I am using git desktop gui on Mac)

Should I reset branchB to the last commit before action (1) ?

And then  create a pull request to merge branchA into branchB ?

If yes, how? Would this be correct?

When on branchB:

```
git reset --hard 4f5oo77

git commit -am "reset to the last commit before merging PR 44"

git push origin
```

**EDIT: this is the log history on branchB**

I wan to go back to commit "4f5oo77 2015-12-01 | Merge pull request #36 from my-repo/branchA"

```
*   87a8888 2015-12-16 | Merge pull request #45 from my-repo/revert-44-branchA (HEAD, origin/branchB, branchB)
|\  
| * 55bd11c 2015-12-16 | Revert "merge branchA" (origin/revert-44-branchA) 
|/  
*   y77447a 2015-12-16 | Merge pull request #44 from my-repo/branchA 
|\  

....

| |/  
* |   4f5oo77 2015-12-01 | Merge pull request #36 from my-repo/branchA
...
```

**EDIT-2** This is what ended up doing:

```
git checkout branchB
git reset --hard 4f5oo77
git push --force-with-lease
```

At this point branchB was back to its "state" before the unwanted merges and I was able to create a pull request for merging branchA into branchB

Comment: Does one of your commits say "Reverted <SHA>"?

Comment: added an edit with the log history for branchB (the one I want merge into) @Makoto

Comment: @Makoto and '*   y77447a 2015-12-16 | Merge pull request #44 from my-repo/branchA ' will be undone? That is the PR I erroneously merged myself...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Except if you REALLY can't modify an history that you already shared (pushed), I think that it's much better to use 'git reset' and 'git push --force-with-lease' instead of ditching your history by stacking revert commits!

Comment: Thanks , it would help me if you could list the exact commands you would run for this example. I am still ramping up with git @philippe

Comment: @klode Sorry I was answering from my phone and 1) it was already a pain to write the answer 2) it was not too hard and I was sure you could handle it ;-)

Comment: I think stacking revert commits is the cleaner solution, even though it doesn't look pretty. Reasons: 1) Your git history actually shows what happened (i.e. you reverted a merge, then you merged again) rather than what would ideally happened ("Just check the git history. That branch was never merged" can lead to a lot of confusion. 2) If you rebase, you really force *everyone else* to do a rebase. That's especially bad because you are probably the only person who fully knows what's happening (i.e. why you rebased and what you rebased).

Comment: @morxa I don't share your point of view. For me history is very important and must be the cleaner possible because when you want to use it, that's already difficult enough to understand without needing "revert stack" (I don't want to have difficulties when using `git blame` or `git bisect` because there is useless commits) and this only because I risk to annoy other users (which is a short term view...)

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that the commits in `branchA` are already in `branchB` (even though they've been reverted by a later commit), so GitHub thinks there's nothing to merge.

At first I thought perhaps you could solve this with `git rebase`, but in reality even `git rebase` will ignore commits that it thinks are already in the branch you are rebasing to. (Surprisingly this is true even when you use the `--no-ff` option, which is supposedly meant to prevent this.)

So instead, you can cherry-pick the commits from `branchA` onto a new branch (such as `branchA-new`), then use that branch to send the PR:

```
git checkout -b branchA-new branchB # Create a new branch off of branchB
git cherry-pick 4f5oo77..branchA # Copy the changes from branchA onto the new branch
```

From there, you should be able to push `branchA-new` up to GitHub and submit a new PR for those changes.

Comment: to make sure I do not mess up branchA, can I create a new branch off of it and rebase branchA-temp onto branchB: `git checkout branchA` then `git checkout -b branchA-temp` then `git rebase branchB` then create pull request to merge branchA-temp into branchB

Comment: I do not really want to change branchA

Comment: Absolutely. Just replace the first command with `git checkout -b branchA-temp branchA`. git doesn't care what the name of the branch is that you're rebasing, and I don't think GitHub cares what branch you're sending the PR from either.

Comment: it does not work, still says that "There aren't any commits to merge".

Comment: Huh, that's weird. Maybe GitHub doesn't check PRs quite the way I thought it did...

Comment: Ah, actually I messed up. Rebase isn't rebasing the commits because it thinks they were already merged... blah. Leme try something else...

Comment: @Ajedi32 While I would suggest a reset in this situation, rebase could work if you use the --interactive option, and then just use all commits.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this blog post about undoing merges](https://git-scm.com/blog/2010/03/02/undoing-merges.html), the best way to solve your issue is:

1. Revert the commit which reverts the merge (in your case: `git revert 55bd11c`)
2. Merge the branch again to get any additional commits which were done after you merged the first time.

This should add all commits from the merged branch without doing any rebasing and/or rewinding.